# SRSS 2016/Report Builder 2016 - row groups not able to collate by date?

Tags: reportbuilder, ssrs-2016

I'm trying to make a report of daily work for a group of users in a database.

it's filtered by a date range, start date and end date. It then shows a list of the users and a total of things they did during that date range.

My boss wants it to then be expandable to show a breakdown of daily totals.

I can get it to open up and show a breakdown, but it's showing like this example here:

7-1-2018 to 7-2-2018

Jane Doe                                      5

```
    7/1/2018           1

    7/1/2018           1

    7/1/2018           1

    7/2/2018           1

    7/2/2018           1
```

I've tried to mess with the groups of which there are currenlty only two, the name and the 'dateindexed' which is the entry in the database for when they do what they do. IT has a time stamp on it was well, but need to just have date and total.

I've tried to aggregate it and it then throws an error about no aggregation being allowed when there are filters present in the report.

Any tips or tricks to get this to collapse down on just the date and give a total for the days?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Without seeing a sample of the data in your dataset, or the results you expect to see its hard to be of much help. As a guess I would say that you need to change your grouping to group by date also (probably no details group required). If the date is actually a timestamp then you will need to convert it first but you can do that in the grouping expression directly.

Comment: The data is pretty much 4 parts from two tables. 

Users table: name & userid
work table: indexedby (userid) and dateindexed (timestamped date). 

The report has a start date, end date and shows all users who registered they indexed things on that day, and then a count. Want to be able to expand that report and show a daily total breakdown as well. 

I can get the overall total and when you expand the group on the name, it then lists everything individually (so if someone indexed 100 documetns a day, they have 100 entries for that day). I've already got the date/time formatted.

Comment: Is the date you are grouping by just a date or is it datetime? If it's datetime you will have to convert it to date in you grouping. Edit the question to show your sample data and grouping expressions